# C# serial connection not working

Tags: c#, io, serial-port

I am trying to send ASCII caracters to a VideoJet Excel 170i printer, via a RS-232 cable (Serial)

When I am using the test program, i have no problem getting a response from the printer, i can change the status of the printer.

This is the code i've made

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1");
    private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string data);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addtoText(string text)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Text = this.richTextBox1.Text + "\n" + text;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            port.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            port.WriteTimeout = 500;

            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.RtsEnable = true;

            port.Open();

            port.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

            addtoText("Port is ready");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Error opening my port: {0}", ex.Message);
            addtoText("Error opening my port: {0}" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(DisplayToUI), new object[] { indata });
    }

    private void DisplayToUI(string displayData)
    {
        addtoText(displayData);

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Write(tbxAscii.Text);
    }

    private void Form1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Close();
    }
}
```

I need to sent ASCII caracters to the printer, like

```
[1B][01][09]
```

To turn the printer to Print Mode.

The printer is supposed to respond, i get no response, and the printer doesn't change its status.

I have a program made to test the serial connection made by the printer, and i can see that all the settings are OK (Baud rate, Parity... port), and indeed on port COM1.

So i think that my port.write is not sending any info to the printer... or maybe i'm sending corrup info and i'm not reading the response of the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure that you want to send `[1B][01][09]` or do you want to send that byte sequence `0x1b,0x01,0x09`

just to see if this works, send the following in you click handler

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bytes = new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x01, 0x09 };
    port.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    port.Flush(); // make sure everything is written
}
```

reading has to be changed, to handle bytes

```
SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

var available = sp.BytesToRead; // check how many bytes are ready to be read
if (available < 1)
    return;

var buffer = new byte[available];
sp.Read(buffer, 0, available);

var indata = BitConverter.ToString(buffer); // convert bytes to a hex representation

this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(DisplayToUI), new object[] { indata });
```

Comment: Sweet it's working, i can turn it off and on! But i'm receiving [][][][] so maybe i'm trying to but a byte into a string.

Comment: Can I ask which commands you were able to implement, is source code available?